# Conditional probability of Negative Binomial R.V. given the SUM of its values

Tags: conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, conditional-expectation

Suppose $\{z_{ij}\}$ are independent ***Negative Binomial*** random variables with means $\{\mu_{ij}\}$, with $i=1\dots I$ and $j=1\dots J$.

How do you find the (expectation of) conditional probability function of $z_{ij}$ given that $y_i = \sum_{j=1}^{J} z_{ij}$ ?

I know that applying the definition of conditional probability you can get the following:

\begin{align}
P\bigg[ z_{i1} = k \bigg| \sum_j z_{ij} = y_i\bigg] &= \frac{P[ z_{i1} = k ∩ \sum_{j=1}^{J} z_{ij} = y_i]}{P[ \sum_{j=1}^{J} z_{ij} = y_i]} \\
&= \frac{P[ z_{i1} = k ∩ \sum_{j=2}^{J} z_{ij} = y_i - k]}{P[ \sum_{j=1}^{J} z_{ij} = y_i]} \\
&= \frac{P[ z_{i1} = k] P[\sum_{j=2}^{J} z_{ij} = y_i - k]}{P[ \sum_{j=1}^{J} z_{ij} = y_i]}
\end{align}

Now, ***IF*** we where dealing with ***Poisson*** R.V.s (which are quite close relatives of NB ones), we could plug into the last equality the following distributions:

$$
z_{i1} \sim Poiss\bigg(\mu_{ij}\bigg)
$$
$$
\sum_{j=2}^{J} z_{ij} \sim Poiss\bigg(\sum_{j=2}^{J} \mu_{ij}\bigg)
$$
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{J} z_{ij} \sim Poiss\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{J} \mu_{ij}\bigg)
$$

and this would result in:

\begin{align}
P\bigg[z_{i1} \bigg| \sum_j z_{ij} = y_i \bigg] &\sim Binomial\bigg(\sum_j z_{ij}, \frac{\mathbb{E}(z_{i1})}{\sum_j\mathbb{E}(z_{i1})} \bigg) \\
&\sim Binomial\bigg(y_{i}, \frac{\mu_{i1}}{\sum_j\mu_{ij}} \bigg)
\end{align}

and the expectation of a Binomial distr $Bin(\alpha, \beta)$ is equal to $\alpha  \beta$,

$$
\mathbb{E}_{ P[z_{ij} | \sum_j z_{ij} = y_i ] } [z_{i1}]= y_i * \frac{\mu_{i1}}{\sum_j\mu_{ij}}
$$

**How can I achieve a similar result when dealing with Negative Binomial random variables?**